# ExtJS 4.2 - Set "width" for list inside combobox

Tags: css, combobox, extjs4, width

I am facing an issue with a combobox using Sencha ExtJS 4.2. I want to show the "dropdown list" with a different width of the component, I mean, only record list should be wider, while the component should remain in the normal size. So when you expand, you can see the records with the full length, but the combobox remains with the default width.

I have tried by setting the width in the lsitConfig, adding styles, but it is not working. What I managed to do so far is to change the width of the list but it shows a scrollbar so you can see the full record text and that is not very user friendly.

I used the Crome Web Developer to check the HTML elements and detected the following css:

```
x-boundlist .x-boundlist-floating, .x-layer, .x-boundlist-default, .x-border-box
```

[image]

If I set the width there, I get what I want. By now I am getting something like this:

[image]

As you can see I can fit the records to handle the full length of its text, but it needs a scroll bar for the user to know what it says.

But when I modify the class attribute I showed you in the first image, it works beautifully and what is more, it retains the combo width, it just exapnds the record list width and that's what I want.

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
forceSelection: false,
required: false,
displayField : 'description',
rowIndex: rowIndex,
name: 'pcrCode1',    
listConfig: {                                                                   
            getInnerTpl: function() {                               
                    return me.formatCPECodeBoxDisplay();
            }
}

formatCPECodeBoxDisplay: function() {
        return '<div style="width:323px;"><tpl if="code != \'\'">{code} : {description}</tpl></div>';
    },
```

If somebody could help me I will really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant information is `minWidth` in the `listConfig` property:

```
    me.directoryPicker = Ext.widget({
        xtype:'combo',
        editable:false,
        store: 'Directory',
        width: 300, // width of the picker
        listConfig:{
            minWidth:500, // width of the list
            maxHeight:400, // height of a list with scrollbar
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
matchFieldWidth: false
```

to your ComboBox config.

Comment: It worked on ExtJs 4.2.3. 
I believe it will work for queryMode: 'local' only.
Tks